# Mobile app development with Ionic and nodejs

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework

Planning to develop a hybrid mobile app with Ionic framework.

Also, with nodejs api's trying to communicate with MySQL database.

Here, do I really need Express of nodeJs?

If yes, what are the exclusive uses of Express and can I use it alongside Ionic framework for the front end?

Thanks
Manikandan J

Answer (score 1):

> Here, do I really need Express of nodeJs?

It's not mandatory to use Express with NodeJS. But it will make your life easier, or else you will have to write code for lot of things.

> If yes, what are the exclusive uses of Express and can I use it
>   alongside Ionic framework for the front end?

Yes you can use it with Ionic. In fact, Ionic is a face of cordova, while express will work like backbone for server side code.

**EDIT 1:**
With Express, lot of features will be readily available, to begin with

1. Can configure static folder path from which files will be directly served.
2. Can configure view rendering engines like Jade. This is specially useful, to separate behavior code from HTML.
3. Can configure middleware which can pre/post process a request in generic way
4. Can configure cookie handling
5. Can introduce routing mechanism and hence promotes modularized development.
6. Can introduce utilities like compression of response (gzip)
   And many more...

Most of these are ready to use modules, while some of them promotes cleaner code. Doing all of these using plain-vanilla JavaScript in NodeJS will take considerable time.

(Sorry, it took a while to update on striking features of Express)

Comment: What exactly, the Express contributes to the application? Please give me clear picture on this.